# Colors within a 'Parcat', with Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I had some difficulties giving color to a 'parcat'. My intentions were to have the last diagram displayed as different colors (for each variable a color). To make this happen I've read the particular documentation for the 'parcat'([plotly.parcat](https://plotly.com/python/parallel-categories-diagram/#basic-parallel-categories-diagram-with-graphobjects)), and have followed the documentation, but I get an error which I can't fix. This is my code:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
# Create dimensions
sex_dim = go.parcats.Dimension(
    values = tips_df['sex'],
    label = "Sex",
    categoryorder = "category ascending"
)

smoker_dim = go.parcats.Dimension(
    values = tips_df['smoker'], 
    label = "Smoker")

day_dim = go.parcats.Dimension(
    values = tips_df['day'], 
    label = "Day",
    categoryorder = "category ascending"
)

time_dim = go.parcats.Dimension(
    values = tips_df['time'], 
    label = "Time",
    categoryorder = "category ascending"
)

size_dim = go.parcats.Dimension(
    values = tips_df['size'], 
    label = "Size",
    categoryorder = "category ascending"
)

quantized_total_bill = go.parcats.Dimension(
    values = tips_df['quantized_total_bill'], 
    label = "Quantized total bill",
    categoryorder = "category ascending"
)

quantized_tip = go.parcats.Dimension(
    values = tips_df['quantized_tip'], 
    label = "Quantized tip",
    categoryorder = "category ascending", 
    categoryarray=[0, 1, 2],
)

# Create parcats trace
color = tips_df.quantized_tip;
colorscale = [[0, 'lightsteelblue'], [1, 'mediumseagreen'], [2, 'yellow']];



# Create parcats trace

fig = go.Figure(data = [go.Parcats(dimensions=[sex_dim, smoker_dim, day_dim, time_dim, size_dim,
                                               quantized_total_bill, quantized_tip],
                                               line={'color': color, 'colorscale': colorscale})])

fig.update_traces(labelfont_color="black")

fig.show()
```

This is the error that I get:

```
ValueError: 
    Invalid element(s) received for the 'color' property of parcats.line
        Invalid elements include: ['Low', 'Low', 'Low', 'Low', 'Low', 'Low', 'Low', 'Low', 'Low', 'Low']
```

Without specifying the colors, I get this plot, which is correct (as I followed the documentation):
[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mxly.png), but when I want to add some colors (like the code above), then an error is given.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me further, as I don't seem to figure it out, while looking at the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my first experience with this type of graph, but to customize the color specification, the range value for the color scale is 0 to 1, whereas the target column for the color is a number from 0 to 1. I use size as the color object column and divide by 10 to stay within 1. Or normalize the color target column.

**Updated:**
Normalized the data for the size columns used as the basis for color coding. Updated code and graphs.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

tips_df = px.data.tips()

# Create dimensions
sex_dim = go.parcats.Dimension(
    values = tips_df['sex'],
    label = "Sex",
    categoryorder = "category ascending"
)

smoker_dim = go.parcats.Dimension(
    values = tips_df['smoker'], 
    label = "Smoker")

day_dim = go.parcats.Dimension(
    values = tips_df['day'], 
    label = "Day",
    categoryorder = "category ascending"
)

time_dim = go.parcats.Dimension(
    values = tips_df['time'], 
    label = "Time",
    categoryorder = "category ascending"
)

size_dim = go.parcats.Dimension(
    values = tips_df['size'], 
    label = "Size",
    categoryarray=[1,2,3,4,5,6],
    categoryorder = "category ascending"
)

quantized_total_bill = go.parcats.Dimension(
    values = tips_df['total_bill'], 
    label = "Quantized total bill",
    categoryorder = "category ascending"
)

quantized_tip = go.parcats.Dimension(
    values = tips_df['tip'], 
    label = "Quantized tip",
    categoryorder = "category ascending", 
    categoryarray=[0, 1, 2],
)

# Create parcats trace
color = [(x- tips_df['size'].min()) / (tips_df['size'].max() - tips_df['size'].min()) for x in tips_df['size']]
colorscale = [[0.0, 'lightsteelblue'], [0.5, 'mediumseagreen'], [1.0, 'yellow']];

# Create parcats trace
fig = go.Figure(data = [go.Parcats(dimensions=[sex_dim, smoker_dim, day_dim, time_dim, size_dim],
                                               line={'color': color, 'colorscale': colorscale})])

fig.update_traces(labelfont_color="black")
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Did you have any issues with my answers?